# The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted

Tags: asp.net

I got this error when I was on the main report page of my web site and try to changes the year from the drop down. The page process heavy data. is it related to heavy data processing?

> The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is
>   invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
>
> Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\51993828\f634ec45\App_Web_hbc8tqe3.0.cs    Line: 0

Comment: What happens when you close your web browser (ALL windows), re-open it, and try again?

Comment: It can happen if you compile a new version of the page, and the refresh a browser with an old version of the page already loaded. The `ViewState` doesn't match up and you get an exception. Hit the URL cleanly and it should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I wonder if it is the session state or the view state.  Either way I couldn't really help you fix the problem with this information.  I might suggest, though, that you use the ability to write this info to SQL server, it appears to be less volitile.